# Mutating of RxSwift Driver value

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, rx-swift

In my application I have an array of notifications. Notification can be read and unread.

When user clicks on the unread notification I need to change the model and reload data in my table view.

In my ViewModel I have output stream:

```
let notifications: Driver<[Notification]>
```

And aslo I have an input stream with notification click:

```
let touchSingleNotificationIntent = PublishSubject<Notification>()
```

When I do something like this I get the error that it's let constant and I cannot mutate it.

```
touchSingleNotificationIntent
        .filter { !$0.isRead }
        .do(onNext: { notification in
            notification.isRead = true // I need to change state of the model immediately after user iteration
        })
        .map { $0.notificationID }
        .flatMap(markNotificationAsRead) // http request which doesn't reply with current notification model status
        .subscribe()
        .disposed(by: bag)
```

Do you have any ideas how to make it mutable? Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing `Notification` is a value type, like a `struct`. Mutating an individual value of `Notification` is meaningless as you are creating a brand new `Notification`. You could try making `Notification` a `class` instead, which is a reference type.

Comment: @daltonclaybrook you're right it's struct, but if I'll change it to class I will affect project architecture. So I'm just trying to find a solution with rx methods.

Answer (score 1):

Streams aren't Mutable at all (this is the same for `Observable`, `Driver`, and any other traits). They are "Read only", you read values off the stream over time.

In general, the conception Observables has a "value" is a bit wrong since Observables represent a value over time, and not just a single value.

What you would want to do is "take into account" your `PublishSubject` when building out your driver.

Something like this would work:

```
notifications = Observable
    .combineLatest(touchedNotification, readNotification, otherEvent) { ($0, $1, $2) }
    .map { ... map the three values into whatever makes sense for you }
    .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ... fallback value ... }
```

Again, the most important fact to remember - You **do not actually mutate streams**, you only combine them, transform them, etc, to create a new stream that suits your needs.

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Parameters of *onNext* are *let* by default. You can define a new one with *var*, i.e. 'var newNotification = notification' and then return it after modifying.

Comment: Hello, It doesn't help to solve the problem because in my output stream is binded for table view and I need mutate object in it.

Comment: You mean you are trying to mutate the *notification* object defined elsewhere? Then you can refer it directly via *self.notifcation* or wherever it is defined. Hard to say without more context.